# Why is my tablesaw whining?

Tags: noise, maintenance, table-saw

I have a Craftsman 113.298031 tablesaw. Recently it has started making a whining sound and the blade is easily bogged down.   Previously the blade bogged down without the noise and I had to tighten the belt. This seems different. I took the belt off and the motor seems to run well by itself. I suspect bearings on the blade assembly but haven't taken it apart yet. Any suggestions before I get started? Likely just lube? Might need new bearings?  Thanks for anything you can do to shorten the repair process.

Comment: how old is the blade? are the teeth loosing their "set"?  shaft spinning and blade bogged down?

Comment: It's a fairly new blade and I see (hear) the problem with multiple blades. It whines before any thing touches the blade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My son had a Craftsman 10” saw that the shiv or pulley connection to the shaft was loose. It would spin up but was noisy and when he tried to cut the blade stopped. I checked it out and the set screw had backed off a bit and it did damage the shaft because he had tightened the belt and it worked for a while before he called. I tightened the set screw on the shaft the shaft to pulley or shiv is not perfect because of the spinning damage but with the screw tight it works fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I found that the set screw is completely missing.  Should be an cheap, easy fix.

Comment: I think my sons was a 1/4-20 if you take the pulley in any hardware or big box store should have them for about a buck.